# Parse through unordered multidimensional array finding only strings

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array of undefined depth.

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    42    => 24,
    "multi" => array(
          "dimensional" => array(
             "array" => "foo",
             "something" => 42,
             "something2" => [1,2,3]
         )
    )
);
```

I need to parse through it, find all the values that are plane text and save them in another array keeping the pathway. So I expect the final array be like this:

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "multi" => array(
          "dimensional" => array(
             "array" => "foo"
         )
    )
);
```

At the moment I'm trying to use recurrent function

```
$this->printAll($array);

public function printAll($a)
    {
        if (!is_array($a)) {
            echo $a, ' <br>'; // here we can check if it is string and add to the final array
            return;
        }

        foreach($a as $i=>$v) {
            $this->printAll($v);
            echo $i;
        }
    }
```

Could someone help me to figure out how to keep indexes through iterations and put it in the final array.

Comment: how long can they array get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function printAll($array, &$save)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $values)
    {
        if ( ! is_numeric($values))
        {
            if (is_array($values))
            {
                printAll($values, $save[$key]);
            }
            else
            {
                $save[$key] = $values;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( ! empty($save)) {
        $save = array_filter($save);
    }
}

$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
     42   => 24,
    "multi" => array(
          "dimensional" => array(
             "array" => "foo",
             "something" => 42,
             "something2" => [1,2,3]
         )
    )
);

$save = array();
printAll($array, $save);

print_r($save);
```

Outputs: [PHP](https://3v4l.org/4LHRp)

```
Array (
     [foo] => bar 
     [multi] => Array ( 
        [dimensional] => Array ( 
              [array] => foo 
)))
```